# React JS shopping cart add functions

Tags: reactjs

Hi guys and privet from Russia :)

I am trying to build a shopping cart but struggling to add certain functionalities by using React JS only (not redux or node)

This is my code so far:

```
App.js

import React from "react";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar />
      <Home />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Home.js*components*
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Home = () => {
  const [basketNumbers, setBasketNumbers] = useState(0);

  const addToBasket = () => {
    setBasketNumbers(setBasketNumbers + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="image">
        <img
          src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn%3AANd9GcTVWhIi-Mq_A6psrTdfOuElSh7p8y5AzevI7cLWnSLAr0BkQlT0&usqp=CAU"
          alt="A green Beautiful dress"
        />
        <h3>Green Dress</h3>
        <h3>15€</h3>
        <a onClick={addToBasket} className="addToCart cart1" href="#">
          Add To Cart
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="image">
        <img
          src="data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
          alt="A beautiful Hot Pink Dress"
        />
        <h3>Pink Dress</h3>
        <h3>350€</h3>
        <a onClick={addToBasket} className="addToCart cart2" href="#">
          Add To Cart
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="image">
        <img
          src="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71dAgPUbwKL._SR500,500_.jpg"
          alt="A beautiful Black Dress"
        />
        <h3>Black Dress</h3>
        <h3>400€</h3>
        <a onClick={addToBasket} className="addToCart cart3" href="#">
          Add To Cart
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="image">
        <img
          src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/He938e0d8636a44c9a4440109bf998d67j/Off-Shoulder-Elegant-Backless-Long-Royal-Blue-Evening-Dresses-2019-Lace-Up-Party-Maxi-Dress-Formal.jpg_640x640q70.jpg"
          alt="A Beautiful Blue Dress"
        />
        <h3>Blue Dress</h3>
        <h3>250€</h3>
        <a onClick={addToBasket} className="addToCart cart 4" href="#">
          Add To Cart
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="image">
        <img
          src="https://ae01.alicdn.com/kf/HTB1Lpp9XAPoK1RjSZKbq6x1IXXaf/Summer-Sexy-Spaghetti-Strap-Ruffle-Women-Dress-Backless-A-Line-Formal-Evening-Party-Dress-Short-Front.jpg_640x640q70.jpg"
          alt="A beautiful Red Dress"
        />
        <h3>Red Dress</h3>
        <h3>150€</h3>
        <a onClick={addToBasket} className="addToCart cart5" href="#">
          Add To Cart
        </a>
      </div>
      <h1>Current Number In Cart {basketNumbers}</h1>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;

Navbar.js *components*

import React from "react";

function Navbar() {

  return (
    <header>
      <div className="overly" />
      <nav>
        <h2>Shop</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li classname="cart">
            {" "}
            <a href="#">
              <ion-icon name="cart" />
              Cart<span> 0 </span>
            </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </header>
  );
}
export default Navbar;

This is my CSS just in case:


li a {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.cart ion-icon {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.cart a {
  background-color: royalblue;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.img {
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.addToCart {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: darkgray;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-align: center;
}

.image:hover .cart1,
.image:hover .cart2,
.image:hover .cart3,
.image:hover .cart4,
.image:hover .cart5 {
  bottom: 50px;
  opacity: 1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

What I would like to add to this code:

1. Add to cart click will add the product to the cart and not just show it on the bottom part of the page
2. Add a total which changes whenever a new item is added to the cart
3. Add a free shipping for a car above 500 EUR, else having a message saying you're not entitled to a free shipping.

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

well i can't actually do all what you want bcs... you shouldn't actually ask people here to add those features for you bcs i think they take so much lines, you should try to add them yourself and then if your code doesnt work, you just ask here, anyways i found a mistake in your code and i'm gonna correct it for ya:

Home.js*components*

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Home = () => {
  const [basketNumbers, setBasketNumbers] = useState(0);

  const addToBasket = () => {
    setBasketNumbers(oldBasketNum => oldBasketNum + 1); //this is the correct way to update the state on click, bcs u wrote setBasketNumbers +1 which won't work
  };

  return (//the rest of your code here)
```

Hope this was helpfull, thanks

**

### Edit:

**

You also should add more components to save you some space in your render method like this:

Item component:

```
import React from "react";

const Item = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="image">
      <img src={props.img} alt={props.alt} />
      <h3>props.name</h3>
      <h3>props.price</h3>
      <a onClick={props.addToBasket} className="addToCart cart1" href="#">
        Add To Cart
      </a>
    </div>
  );
};
export default Item;
```

Home.js component:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Item from "./item.js";

const Home = () => {
  const [basketNumbers, setBasketNumbers] = useState(0);

  const addToBasket = () => {
    setBasketNumbers((oldBasketNum) => oldBasketNum + 1); //this is the correct way to update the state on click, bcs u wrote setBasketNumbers +1 which won't work
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Item name="" price="" img="" alt="" /> //you fill this props as you want
      the items to be
      <Item name="" price="" img="" alt="" /> //you could also make this more
      dynamic using arrays
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Salah, I am sorry but I was not aware and I was struggling with this one quite a lot..thank you for your advice <3